# What does prototype mean in MongoDB shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

when I input

```
DB.prototype
```

the mongodb shell said

```
undefined
```

But when i input

```
DB.prototype.dropDatabase
```

It return the source code of the method 'dropDatabase'.
So,what the prototype means?So does DB?

Comment: What you are doing is typing into the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) shell. This is a JavaScript based REPL environment and therefore all the methods conform to JavaScript objects. This has nothing to do with MongoDB itself, but is simply an artifact of using a JavaScript REPL as a vehicle for implementing a command execution environment.

Comment: I know little about JavaScript.May prototype is just a JavaScript objcets? @NeilLunn